# Preventing display of incorrectly sized Community Ads

Tags: bug, community-promotion-ads

At the GIS Stack Exchange we currently have a Community Ad that displays as below:

[image]

whereas the [GIS Meta Answer from which it is derived](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5159/115) looks like this:

[image: The OSGEO Conference]

The instructions to Community Ad posters is that

> The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.

Is it a bug that a different sized image can be posted and displayed?

Comment: I don't believe there has ever been anything in the code that attempts to check the image sizes. We've always depended on manual intervention when something is wrong.

Comment: Are you going to change this into a feature request? If not, think it's more a support question than bug report.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou I thought I'd leave it to the mods/CMs to decide how they wanted it handled.  I have no objection to them changing its leading tag and setting a status on it.

Comment: This could be fixed with a `height: auto;`, to be fair

Answer (score 3):

As [commented by @Animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345529/preventing-display-of-incorrectly-sized-community-ads#comment1157657_345529):

> I don't believe there has ever been anything in the code that attempts
>   to check the image sizes. We've always depended on manual intervention
>   when something is wrong.

and they have proceeded to delete the posts with the incorrectly sized images.

This clears the way for a correctly sized image to be included in the original post (to then be undeleted by an SO staff member or a GIS SE moderator) or a new similar post.

---

A correctly sized image was provided by @Rob and used to replace the original image in the original post.  It now displays well when its turn in the Community Ad rotation comes up:

[image]